# How can I pass MemoryStream data to unmanaged C++ DLL using P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, parameter-passing, memorystream

I need your help with the following scenario:

I am reading some data from hardware into a MemoryStream (C#) and I need to pass this data in memory to a dll implemented in unmanaged C++ (using pointer ??).
The data read (into stream) is very large (megabytes). I understand that I can P/Invoke this dll but what I am not sure is how to pass the pointer / reference of the stream data to the C++ API ?

I must admit I am confused as I am new to C# - do I need to use unsafe / fixed since data is large or these are irrelevant as MemoryStream object is managed by GC ? Some example code / detailed description would be very helpful. Thanks

Signature of unmanaged API:

```
BOOL doSomething(void * rawData, int dataLength)
```

Comment: What data type does the C++ dll require?

Comment: It require raw data - byte / void*. I can change the dll API as required.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's just expecting bytes you can read the MemoryStream into a byte array and then pass a pointer to that to the method.

You have to declare the external method:

```
[DllImport("mylibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool doSomething(IntPtr rawData, int dataLength);
```

Then, read the bytes from the MemoryStream into a byte array. Allocate a [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) which:

> Once allocated, you can use a GCHandle
> to prevent the managed object from
> being collected by the garbage
> collector when an unmanaged client
> holds the only reference. Without such
> a handle, the object can be collected
> by the garbage collector before
> completing its work on behalf of the
> unmanaged client.

And finally, use the AddrOfPinnedObject method to get an IntPtr to pass to the C++ dll.

```
private void CallTheMethod(MemoryStream memStream)
{
   byte[] rawData = new byte[memStream.Length];
   memStream.Read(rawData, 0, memStream.Length);
   
   GCHandle rawDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   try
   {
     IntPtr address = rawDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject ();

     doSomething(address, rawData.Length);
   }
   finally
   {
     if (rawDataHandle.IsAllocated)
       rawDataHandle.Free();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes this method basically is for compression so it will require / operate on raw data passed to it. 
Also just curious unsafe tagged data is placed on heap or stack in C# ?

Comment: Thank you so much scotty2012. Appreciate your help

Comment: Oh man, this even works in Silverlight. How great. Thanks, scottm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if you have a `MemoryStream` there is no reason to copy the data (a `MemoryStream` is just a wrapper around a `byte[]`). Instead, you can access the internal `byte[]` array directly by using the [`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @NightOwl888 OP requirement is passing args to `doSomething(void * rawData, int dataLength)`