# C++ application and C# application having shared region/memory

Tags: c#, c++

I have an issue to create a C++ application and C# application those two must have a shared region between them, so both of them can Read/Write from/to this region. if you have any documents/solution can you share it to me?
thanks in Advance.....

Comment: What is the kind of these applications? Where is this region situated: server, file, memory stream? Don't ask SO chaotically, write concrete things

Comment: @ Elliot Tereschuk it's memory stream

Comment: [Sharing a memory stream between C# and unmanaged C++ applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054009/how-can-i-pass-memorystream-data-to-unmanaged-c-dll-using-p-invoke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a named pipe so the two processes can communicate (C# server and C++ Client)

you can also see ["Sharing Files and Memory"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to communicate between applications, along with mutexs and events to single between applications.